# Error: locator.waitFor: Error: strict mode violation: locator() resolved to 4 elements

Tags: robotframework, playwright

I have an html page where there are 4 buttons that refer to the same class and therefore create disambiguity in test automation. I have tried different approaches and the one that comes closest to the solution is counting the elements and clicking one at a time via loop but still it doesn't work, the same error appears.
What can be done in these cases?

```
*** Keywords ***
    ${buttonCounter}=    Get Element Count    css=.delete-filter.tgk-button.btn.btn-link-danger
    FOR    ${index}    IN RANGE    1    ${buttonCounter+1}
        ${button_selector}=    Set Variable    xpath=(//button[contains(@class, 'delete-filter') and contains(@class, 'tgk-button') and contains(@class, 'btn') and contains(@class, 'btn-link-danger')])[${index}]
        Click    ${button_selector}
    END
```

I expect to click on this delete-filter buttons

Answer (score 0):

Playwright found 4 elements. Have you tried .first() ?

```
page.locator('.delete-filter.tgk-button.btn.btn-link-danger).first().click()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to select the first element you can try `.first().click()`

If possible you can add a data-testid attributes to the html element. For example `<button data-testid='delete-filter-button' />`. This makes it also less error prone as classes tend to change from time to time.